# black screen in login Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, login-screen

If I turn on my PC and not my monitor when I turn on my monitor the display is black and I don't see the login.
I must turn on the monitor before I turn on the PC to see the login.
With the screen off after a period of inactivity when I move the mouse screen is black. I have to close the app and open again and everything goes OK.

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: e7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=3840,2160
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Hello Nmath, 
yes, I try to install propietary drivers from amd website but I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. If the monitor is off during the boot, ubuntu does not display the login screen.

However, I have discover that if you write the password in that black screen the session starts.